# Спрятать часть изображения

Tags: html, css

На данном примере мы видим, что изображение не помещается по высоте в заданную область и сжимает не пропорционально.

Как показать только ту часть изображения, которая вмещается, а остальное спрятать за div?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  background: black;
}

div img {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bgH2tvk.jpg">
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div img {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bgH2tvk.jpg">
<div>
```